# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews Using Dropdown Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview, dropdown

I'm using the RN library `react-native-dropdown-picker` but when i wrap this component with ScrollView it returns a warning of

> VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

I've tried several solutions like `nestedScrollEnabled`, `vertical = true` , `horizontal= true` but none of them worked for me, I also tried

`LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested']);`
this line can remove warning but when i try to scroll DropDownPicker it won't scroll,
check the below code, maybe there is a issue with my code..

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  <View style={{zIndex: 3, marginBottom: 20}}>
              <Text style={{paddingLeft: 5, paddingBottom: 5}}>
                Vehicle Type <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>*</Text>
              </Text>
              <DropDownPicker
                open={state.open_vehicle_type}
                value={state.vehicle_type}
                scrollViewProps={{
                  decelerationRate: 'fast',
                  nestedScrollEnabled: true,
                  style: {
                    zIndex: 1222,
                  },
                }}
                items={[
                  {label: 'Car', value: 'Car'},
                  {label: 'Truck', value: 'Truck'},
                  {label: 'Van', value: 'Van'},
                  {label: 'Bike', value: 'Bike'},
                ]}
                placeholder="vehicle type"
                placeholderStyle={{color: color_theme.black_20}}
                onClose={() => setState({open_vehicle_type: false})}
                setOpen={() => setState({open_vehicle_type: true})}
                closeAfterSelecting={true}
                setValue={value => {
                  setState({
                    vehicle_type: value(state.vehicle_type),
                  });
                }}
                style={{
                  borderColor: color_theme.black_20,
                  backgroundColor: color_theme.white,
                }}
                dropDownContainerStyle={{
                  borderColor: color_theme.black_20,
                  backgroundColor: color_theme.white,
                }}
                multiple={false}
                mode="BADGE"
              />
            </View>
  </ScrollView>
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

i have the multiple fields in so maybe ScrollView is req for that..

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is telling you that you should not nest a ScrollView inside another ScrollView. This is because ScrollViews are virtualized lists, and nested virtualized lists can cause problems with windowing and other functionality.

To fix this, you can use a different container for the DropDownPicker component. For example, you could use a View or a Flexbox container.

Here is an example of how to fix the problem:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{zIndex: 3, marginBottom: 20}}>
              <Text style={{paddingLeft: 5, paddingBottom: 5}}>
                Vehicle Type <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>*</Text>
              </Text>
              <View>
                <DropDownPicker
                  open={state.open_vehicle_type}
                  value={state.vehicle_type}
                  items={[
                    {label: 'Car', value: 'Car'},
                    {label: 'Truck', value: 'Truck'},
                    {label: 'Van', value: 'Van'},
                    {label: 'Bike', value: 'Bike'},
                  ]}
                  placeholder="vehicle type"
                  placeholderStyle={{color: color_theme.black_20}}
                  onClose={() => setState({open_vehicle_type: false})}
                  setOpen={() => setState({open_vehicle_type: true})}
                  closeAfterSelecting={true}
                  setValue={value => {
                    setState({
                      vehicle_type: value(state.vehicle_type),
                    });
                  }}
                  style={{
                    borderColor: color_theme.black_20,
                    backgroundColor: color_theme.white,
                  }}
                  dropDownContainerStyle={{
                    borderColor: color_theme.black_20,
                    backgroundColor: color_theme.white,
                  }}
                  multiple={false}
                  mode="BADGE"
                />
              </View>
  </ScrollView>
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```